# from solidity: TypeError: Member "log" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(library console)

Tags: solidity, remix, hardhat, logs, console

from solidity: TypeError: Member "log" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(library console).

Im using hardhats lib "hardhat/console.sol";

I want to console.log the mapping and its members also, How can I do that ?

[image]

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// OpenZeppelin Contracts (last updated v4.6.0) (token/ERC20/ERC20.sol)

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "../Tokens/ERC1155.sol";
import "../Interface/IJACKPOT.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

import "../utils/BokkyPooBahsDateTimeContract.sol";
import "../utils/randomNumberGenerator.sol";
import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "./AkumaToken20.sol";

contract JackPot is IJACKPOT{
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;


    ///convert all Counters to UINT256

    //Helpers
    // akumacoin address and user address 
    function getAkumaCoinBalance(address userAddress) public view returns(uint256)
    {
     IERC20 token = IERC20(0x07f658C9fd773dEC2F0a9bB54f6dDDC4e2F3012D);
     return token.balanceOf(userAddress); 
    }

    function getStringLength(string memory mystring)internal pure returns(uint256){
        return bytes(mystring).length;
    }

    function getCounter()internal view returns(uint256){
        return uint256(_counter._value);
    }

    function getParticipantAddresses(uint256 counter)
    external 
    override 
    view
    returns(address[] memory)
    {
        return _jackPots[counter]._participants;
    }

    function calculateRandomWinnerFromList(address[] memory participants,uint256 counter)
    external
    override
    returns(address)
    {
        uint256 winnerIndex = random.random(participants);
        //get send list and get random number from it
        address winner = _jackPots[counter]._participants[winnerIndex]; //winners address
        //single out the winner
        _jackPots[counter]._participants[winnerIndex] = 
        _jackPots[counter]._participants[ _jackPots[counter]._participants.length - 1 ];
        //then delete that position
        _jackPots[counter]._participants.pop();
        //then return the array of rest of the participants
        return winner;
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
struct jackPot{
        uint256 _jackPotId;
        uint256 _startTime;
        uint256 _endTime;
        uint256 _toMint; //counts how many number of times it is going to minted and transfered
        uint256 _entryFee;
        uint256 _prizePool;
        uint256 _nftPrizeGiven; //both acting as bool
        uint256 _prizePoolGivenToAll; //bool to check if prize of either is given
        address[] _participants; 
        string _name;
    }


    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //Counter -> JackPot
    mapping(uint256=>jackPot) internal _jackPots;
    
    Counters.Counter internal _counter;

    BokkyPooBahsDateTimeContract _dateTime;
    RandomNumber random;

    uint256[] _jackPotIds;

    constructor(){
        _dateTime = new BokkyPooBahsDateTimeContract();
        random = new RandomNumber();
    }

    function createJackpot(uint256 jackPotId,uint256 startTime,uint256 endTime,uint256 entryFee ,string memory name) 
    override
    external
    {   

        require(jackPotId>=0,"JackPot Id cannot be 0");
        require(startTime>_dateTime._now(),"StartT ime should be greater than Current Time");
        require(endTime>_dateTime._now(),"End Time should be greater than Current Time");
        require(getStringLength(name)>=0,"Name Length is not valid");
        require(endTime>startTime,"Start Time cannot be greater than start Time");
        require(startTime!=endTime,"Start and End Time cannot be equal");
        //optional, Check if date is unix timestamp
        address[] memory emptyList; //givng an empty string list for participants

        _jackPots[getCounter()] = jackPot(
            jackPotId,
            startTime,
            endTime,
            0,
            entryFee,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            emptyList,
            name
        );

        console.log(_jackPots[getCounter()]._name);
        console.log(_jackPots[getCounter()]._jackPotId);
        console.log(_jackPots[getCounter()]._startTime);
        console.log(_jackPots[getCounter()]._endTime);
        console.log(_jackPots[getCounter()]._entryFee);

        console.log("Counter Func",getCounter());
        console.log("Before Counter",_counter._value);   
        _counter.increment();
        console.log("After Counter",_counter._value);
        _jackPotIds.push(jackPotId);

        emit jackPotCreatedEvent(jackPotId,name,block.timestamp);
    }
    
    function getJackpot(uint256 counter) 
    public
    view  
    returns(jackPot memory)
    {  
        console.log(_jackPots[counter]._name);
        console.log(_jackPots[counter]._jackPotId);
        console.log(_jackPots[counter]._startTime);
        console.log(_jackPots[counter]._endTime);
        console.log(_jackPots[counter]._entryFee);

        return _jackPots[counter];
    }

    function getStartAndEndTimeOfJackPot(uint256 tokenId) external override view returns (uint256,uint256)
    {
        console.log( _jackPots[tokenId]._endTime , _jackPots[tokenId]._startTime );
        return ( _jackPots[tokenId]._endTime , _jackPots[tokenId]._startTime );
    }
    //AkumaToken Address
    function insertPartcipantsInJackpot(address tokenAddress,uint256 counter,address payable participant) override external 
    {   /*
        console.log(IERC20(tokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this)));
        //checks the custom token balance
        require(IERC20(tokenAddress).balanceOf(address(this)) >= _jackPots[counter]._entryFee,
         "Not Sufficent Funds");+

        console.log("Here");
        require(_jackPots[counter]._endTime > _dateTime._now(),
        "This Participant Cannot Enter This Jackpot, Because The Event has already started");
        */
        AkumaCoin(0x07f658C9fd773dEC2F0a9bB54f6dDDC4e2F3012D).transfer(0x001286211EcDb2ED5043f50d6634d7be924eF5D9,_jackPots[counter]._entryFee);
        //deduct that amount,sent to owner account or can be done to contract itself

        _jackPots[counter]._prizePool += _jackPots[counter]._entryFee;
        //put that entry fee in that pool

        _jackPots[counter]._toMint++;

        _jackPots[counter]._participants.push(participant);
    }
    
    function getAllJackpot() //returns all jackpotIds
    external
    view 
    override 
    returns(uint256[] memory)
    {   
        return _jackPotIds;
    }

    function prizePoolDistribution(uint256 jackPotId)
    external
    payable
    override
    returns(uint256)
    {
        require(_dateTime._now() >= _jackPots[jackPotId]._endTime ,
        "Time has not passed enough for this JackPot");
        require(_dateTime.get15DaysSeconds() >= _jackPots[jackPotId]._endTime,"15 Days have not passed for this jackpot");
        //check time after endTime ,that has it been 15 days ?
        require(_jackPots[jackPotId]._nftPrizeGiven < 1, "Prize NFT Already Given to Winner");
        
        address[] memory participants = this.getParticipantAddresses(jackPotId);
        //SideNote to call another implemented external function, use this keyword
        //then make a function in which the participants list is passed
        
        address winner =  this.calculateRandomWinnerFromList(participants,jackPotId);
        //generate a single random number from the list of participants length
        //return that address and rest of the list excluding that winner
        
        IERC20(0x7EF2e0048f5bAeDe046f6BF797943daF4ED8CB47).transfer(winner,_jackPots[jackPotId]._prizePool);
        _jackPots[jackPotId]._prizePool = 0;
        //transfers prize from prize pool to winner and makes that poll 0
        _jackPots[jackPotId]._nftPrizeGiven = 1;
        //checks if given nft prize given
        emit prizeDistributedEvent(jackPotId,block.timestamp,_jackPots[jackPotId]._participants);
        return 1;
    }

    function nftPrizeDistribution(uint256 jackPotId,address to,uint256 tokenId) external override payable returns(uint256){
        require(_dateTime._now() >= _jackPots[jackPotId]._endTime ,
        "Time has not passed enough for this JackPot");
        
        require(_dateTime.get15DaysSeconds() >= _jackPots[jackPotId]._endTime,"15 Days have not passed for this jackpot");
        //check time after endTime ,that has it been 15 days ?

        require(_jackPots[jackPotId]._prizePoolGivenToAll < 1, "Prize has been distributed to all participants");
        //checks if prize has been distributed to all participants

            //goes backwards 9,8,7...0     //tomint greater than equal to 0
        for(_jackPots[jackPotId]._toMint ; _jackPots[jackPotId]._toMint >=0;){
            
            //before mint gas check
            require(gasleft()>=200,"Not much gas left,try again");
            require(_jackPots[jackPotId]._toMint>1,"all nfts have been given to participants");

            //mint, enter custom values
            ERC1155(0xDA0bab807633f07f013f94DD0E6A4F96F8742B53).
            _mint(to,tokenId,1,"");
 
            _jackPots[jackPotId]._toMint--;

            if(_jackPots[jackPotId]._toMint==0){
               _jackPots[jackPotId]._prizePoolGivenToAll=1;
               break;
            }//checks if given to all nfts
     
            //after mint gas check
            require(_jackPots[jackPotId]._toMint>1,"all nfts have been given to participants");
            require(gasleft()>=200,"Not much gas left,try again");
        }
        emit prizeDistributedEvent(jackPotId,block.timestamp,_jackPots[jackPotId]._participants);
        return 1;
    }


}
```

Comment: Could you show your code please ? (just a minimal example to reproduce your issue) This would greatly help to figure out where the issue is.

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/users/84305/hroussille Added Image to Post.

Comment: Better put the actual code instead of an image, plus it doesn't show your version and imports.

Comment: @hroussille here.

Comment: You must to include all your smart contract code. It's impossible to give you a solution with only piece of code.

Comment: @Kerry99 have a look

Comment: @Kerry99 have a look

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have this error, because `console.sol` doesn't accept struct type inside `console.log` method. You can see what types accept console.log in original smart contract code ([here](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/blob/master/packages/hardhat-core/console.sol)).